# Employee and EmployeeInfo - C# relationship

Tags: c#, .net, aggregation, composition, class-relationship

I have two classes.

```
Employee (Model)

EmployeeInfo (Another Class)
//Employee GetEmployeeInfo(int empCode) (MethodName)
```

`EmployeeInfo` class returns a `Employee` type.

Now, what is the `relationship` between `Employee` and `EmployeeInfo` ?
(Aggregation, Composition or Association ?)

My guess is that, a new instance of `Employee` is created within the `EmployeeInfo`. So, when `EmployeeInfo` class object dies, so does `Employee` . This signifies a `death relationship`. So, the relationship is `Composition` ?

Sorry if this is a naive question, but cant get it right.

Comment: You mean the `EmployeeInfo` class contains an `Employee` type, not returns, right?

Comment: @Rufus: No. Actually, `EmployeeInfo` class has a method called `GetEmployee` and it returns `Employee` type.

Comment: Is EmployeeInfo a static or instance class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a particular EmployeeInfo is created with and dies with a specific Employee then it's Composition.

If a particular EmployeeInfo can have a specific Employee, but can exist without it then it's Aggregation.

Both Composition and Aggregation are types of Associations, they are just specialized associations.

Yes I would say the relationship you are describing would be composition.

Answer (score 0):

It could be either Composition if EmployeeInfo owns (creates/disposes) the Employee, or Association (if Employee may exist outside EmployeeInfo).

So more information on how you use them (source code) is needed to answer your question.

Answer (score -2):

Strange, these two classes is designed by you? If not , it's hard to know the relationship between the two.

Comment: He's asking for the name of the design pattern.

Comment: Your answer is not an answer...